# What to do if Flex Builder 3 debugger unable to start

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex-builder-3

I'm using Flex Builder 3 now and it suddenly refuses to start debugging session. I've reinstalled debugger versions of Flash Player: both 9 and 10 versions. Then I've reinstalled Flex Builder itself allowing it to install it's native Flash Player version. And finally, I've tried to use both IE and Firefox as host for player under debug. How on Earth I could diagnose what happened with FB? Thank you.

**PS** I've turned firewall of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem and this is how it was solved:
http://therush.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/resolved-flex-builder-3-debugger-stopped-working

If this doesn't solve it:
Try to see (with netstat -an on win) if flash player is listening to debug connections.
If it isn't, its a problem with player.
If it is, try to check builder properties to see if it tries to connect to correct port.
Try to telnet to said port to see if player responds.

Answer (score 1):

The debug player uses a socket connection to talk to the debugger, perhaps you've installed something that blocks this connection (likely a software firewall or virus program)?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned reinstalling. Just to be meticulous, did you use the "uninstaller" tool? http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_14157 . Uninstalling from the Windows add/remove UI doesn't work properly.

Once you get it fixed, if you have a need to test against more than one release (9 and 10), you might check this tool out: http://geekglue.blogspot.com/2007/12/iflash-switcher-installing-new-player.html . (It's currently available as a Firefox plugin.)